# Узнать имя контрола, не зная его типа

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть обработчик событий, в котором мне нужно узнать имя котрола, который в него попал.
Но проблема в том, что к этому обработчику привязаны разные по типу котролы. И узнать него простым `((Panel)sender).Name` не получается, т.к. нет определённого типа.

Comment: `(Control)sender`. Все контролы напрямую или опосредовано унаследованы от класса `Control`, который имеет свойство `Name`. Поэтому их все можно приводить к этому типу.

Comment: Смотрите в документации иерархию предков (Inheritance) и потомков (Derived): [Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), [Panel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.panel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Не используйте Name для таких задач, используйте Tag